# useradd -p option

Tags: command-line, su, useradd, passwd

I can't understand the purpose of -p option in 'useradd'

 Let's create a user

```
useradd -m -p 'pass1' user1
```

after running the command above, when trying to log in using `su - user1`
authentication fails.
another problem is that password is not encrypted in /etc/passwd file, if I run `cat /etc/passwd | grep user1` I get `user1:pass1:19196:0:99999:7:::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to provide the encrypted password to the `-p` option. From the `useradd(8)` man page:

```
       -p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The 
           default is to disable the password.

           Note: This option is not recommended because the password
           (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing 
           the processes.
```

The value you provide is used verbatim in the `passwd` file, so of course if you provide an unencrypted value you'll never be able to log in using that password.

---

Something like this works:

```
useradd -m \
  -p "$(python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("pass1"))')" \
  testuser
```

(But do note the warning in the man page about potentially exposing the password to other system users.)